# How can I run a Windows-based asp.net core project with a macOS visual code application?

Tags: windows, macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have a project written in asp.net C# and I have been using visual studio in Windows for years. I bought a MACBOOK pro and installed the Visual Code application as well as the SDK application, but I still cannot run my project neither from the terminal nor from the debug. There is no problem with IIS, I just get errors like Microsoft.WebAplication.Targets or csc. I made json files but there is still an error in the targets. Can someone please help me step by step on how to run a windows project on a macos?

```
   
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!--<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />-->
  <!--<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />-->
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>1830</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost:1830/</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props'))" />
  </Target>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: That's *not* an ASP.NET Core project file. This isn't about Windows, that project type simply can't be used in ASP.NET Core. You can't just make a few tweaks and compile the old code either. The ASP.NET Core documentation has an entire [section on Migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-8.0) with guidance for specific project types (Web Forms, MVC, Web API). There's also the [.NET Upgrade Assistant](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.upgradeassistant) to detect problems, automate some migration tasks

Comment: What kind of project are you trying to migrate? It matters a lot. Web Forms was never migrated to ASP.NET Core - it's just too old. The only option in that case is to create a new Razor Pages, MVC or Blazor app and have it run side-by-side with the old app, migrating functionality to the new app in steps. That may be impossible for you - there's no way to compile or run ASP.NET Framework apps on a Mac. You'll need a Windows VM or a separate Windows machine at least

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Maybe I didn't explain it to you well, also thank you very much for your reply. This is what I need: How can I run an asp.net core project written in C# on Windows with visual code on macOS? Why do I always get targets error? When I type dotnet build, I always get target error.

Comment: That's not an ASP.NET Core project. You can't build or run ASP.NET projects on a Mac unless you use a Windows VM. Period. The question you asked is wrong, not misunderstood.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand now. thank you very much. I just have one last question: If I want to set up and write an ERP system on macOS, what kind of interface should I have to buy who connect my MSSQL database too? What kind of tamplate should I buy so that visual code can also run and connect to the MSSQL database? I want to can write code and set up a Bootstrap supported UI to make ERP system.